# How do I extrude a square face inward?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

I know this is a basic question, but I didn't know where else to find the answer.

I  want to extrude the top face of this rail straight downward, but when I do this it leaves 2 extra faces.

I want a result similar to what I have now, but without the faces that I marked.

Is there a way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: I need the marked faces removed.]

Comment: Do it the other way around. Extrude upwards

Comment: Hi. I did extrude downwards. My end goal is to get the straight edges unlike when I just move the face downward.